# Error in using Metaclasses in graphene

Tags: python, metaprogramming, metaclass, graphene-python

I am trying to make a meta class for my graphene.ObjectType subclass. My main objective is to make attributes of class (i.e. fields of Graphene Object) from some list of strings that contain their names.

For eg. `list = ['quantity', 'position']`

For this list, my class `Attack` must something be like this :

```
class Attack(graphene.ObjectType):
    quantity = graphene.String()
    position = graphene.String()
```

The way I am doing this is as follows :

```
import graphene
from graphene.types.objecttype import ObjectType, ObjectTypeMeta

class mytype(ObjectTypeMeta):
    def __new__(cls, clsname, base, clsdict):
        print "Hello"
        setattr(cls, 'quantity', graphene.String())
        return ObjectTypeMeta.__new__(cls, clsname, base, clsdict)

class combined_meta(mytype, ObjectTypeMeta):
    pass

class Attack(graphene.ObjectType):
    __metaclass__ = combined_meta
    def __init__(self, dic):
        self.quantity = "123"
        print "Hello world"
        print dic

class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    attack = graphene.Field(Attack)
    def resolve_attack(self, args, context, info):
        return Attack(dict())

schema = graphene.Schema(query = Query)

query = '''
{
    attack
}
'''

result = schema.execute(query)
print result.data
```

I see `"Hello"` with many errors..

```
AssertionError: Attack fields must be a mapping (dict / OrderedDict) with field names as keys or a function which returns such a mapping.
```

Am I doing anything wrong...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating your `__new__` in an incorrect way. The first parameter to the metaclass' `__new__` is the metaclass itself, not the class you are creating. The actual "cls" that is being created is the return of `type.__new__` - which in this case is called by `ObjectTypeMeta.__new__`.
On the other hand, the fourth parameter you get there is the class namespace - it is the correct place to inject your new attribute.

So, just try something like this:

```
import graphene
from graphene.types.objecttype import ObjectType, ObjectTypeMeta

class mytype(ObjectTypeMeta):
    def __new__(metacls, clsname, base, clsdict):
        print "Hello"
        clsdict['quantity'] = graphene.String()
        return ObjectTypeMeta.__new__(metacls, clsname, base, clsdict)

...
```